# Nested Div at Full Width Expands out of Bounds

Tags: css

I have a form centered in a main with flex. When I set the elements of the form to width 100% they extend past the max width of the form element:

[image: Form Head and Text Extends Beyond Form Max Width]

```html
<main style='display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; height: 100vh;'>
  <form method="POST" action="process_this_form.php">
    <input name="title" type="text" required style="width: 100%;" />
    <textarea name="text" required style="width: 100%;"></textarea>
  </form>
</main>
```

Comment: You need to set the [box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) for elements to border-box. By default it is based on content https://nimb.ws/28xEoT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As m4n0 commented, you need to set `box-sizing: border-box` on your form elements.

`<input>` and `<textarea>` contain default *padding* and *borders*. The default behaviour when you declare `width: 100%` is that the content is 100% width and that the padding and border be added **on top** of that width.

By declaring `box-sizing: border-box` - borders and padding will be included in the 100% width rather than adding to it.

```css
form * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<main style='display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; height: 100vh;'>
  <form method="POST" action="process_this_form.php">
    <input name="title" type="text" required style="width: 100%;" />
    <textarea name="text" required style="width: 100%;"></textarea>
  </form>
</main>
```